# Performance difference using dynamic number of threads

Tags: c++, dynamic, openmp

I'm using openMP to parallize some heavy loops, and it works as expected.

Testing showed that this directive gave the most performance:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(7)
```

However, that may differ from machine to machine. Also, i wanted to be able to switch threading on/off using a runtime switch.

Therefore, i figured i could use something like this:

```
if(shouldThread)
    omp_set_num_threads(optimalNumberOfThreadsForThisMachine);
else
    omp_set_num_threads(1);
```

Where on my computer, the optimal number of threads is 7 in this example. Then, use this directive instead:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

It works well - except that the code compiled with the second directive is about 50% slower. Is this to be expected? I figure the runtime has to do dynamic dispatching and work scheduling, while the compile-time directive can add some sort of optimization, i guess.

Code is compiled with msvc 2013, on an core i7-3740

Comment: You can also control parallelisation at runtime via the `if` clause: `#pragma omp parallel ... if(run_in_par)` where `run_in_par` evaluates to zero (the parallel region is inactivated) or to non-zero (the parallel region is activated). Other than that, the compiler is not that smart and having the code in the second case be 50% slower is probably due to something else.

Comment: I guess. That was my first idea too, but that amounted to doubling some 2000 lines of code which i would rather avoid. I also loose the ability to dynamically tune the number of threads.

Comment: Those can be combined: `parallel ... num_threads(nthreads) if(run_in_par)`. And why you should double code? It's just a clause that you add to your existing OpenMP `parallel` regions.